# Заменить расширение php на html в Microsoft IIS

Tags: .htaccess, iis

Как я могу заменить расширение php на html всех файлов через web.config в Microsoft IIS?
С помощью .htacces на apache делал так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже решил)

```
<rule name="rule 1G" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)\.html$"  />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php"  />
</rule>
```